# Убрать пробелы при выводе

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть вот такой код

```
 for i in range (0, len(m),2):
        print((m[i],m[i+1]), sep ='', end=" ")
```

И выводит он, например: `(220, 224) (1184, 1210)`, а мне нужно `(220,224)
(1184,1210)`

Я пробовал *sep*, но это ничего не меняет. Как **убрать пробелы** между парами?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```py
m = '12342134' # пример того, как может задаваться m. У вас он задаётся списком/кортежем, но для примера достаточно задать его и строкой
for i in range (0, len(m), 2):
  s = str((m[i], m[i+1]))
  print(s[0:s.index(' ')] + s[s.index(' ')+1:len(s)], sep = '', end = ' ')
```

Результат:

```py
('1','2') ('3','4') ('2','1') ('3','4')
```

## UPD

Были нарекания в комментариях на то, что в результате кортежи содержат строки, а не числа. Это связано с входными данными (т.к. в примере `m`- строка). Вот пример для списка чисел:

```py
m = [225, 412, 5, -41, 4, -241]
for i in range (0, len(m), 2):
  s = str((m[i], m[i+1]))
  print(s[0:s.index(' ')] + s[s.index(' ')+1:len(s)], sep = '', end = ' ')
```

Результат:

```py
(225,412) (5,-41) (4,-241)
```

Всё прекрасно работает и для списков чисел =)

Comment: Супер! Спасибо.

Comment: у вас в скобках числа в кавычках, а у автора без (если это конечно для него важно)

Comment: @whizz169 Это кстати да, возможно тесты не проходятся из-за этого

Comment: @Mikey_mouse обновил решение, проверьте

Comment: @Евгений да теперь и с вашим решением я имею 47% верных тестов, видимо нужно разбираться в задаче, спасибо

Answer (score 5):

```
m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]

for i in range(0, len(m), 2):
    print('{2}{0},{1}{3}'.format(m[i], m[i+1], '(', ')'), end=" ")
```

вывод

```
(1,2) (3,4) (5,6) (7,8) (7,6) (5,4)
```

Comment: Я конечно не очень разбираюсь с чем это может быть связано, но с вашим кодом я имею уже 46.7% верных тестов, с предыдущем вариантом человека сверху  28.5%

Comment: @Mikey_mouse странно. Может дополните вопрос полным условием задания? Вдруг в нем есть какие-то моменты

Comment: Нет ну это при том, что основную часть кода я вообще не трогал.